# Where is my JSON contact list after `npm run build` in React?

Tags: reactjs, json, database, api

I have created my React Web App (NodeJs) and deployed it online. The app includes contact form that uploads the data to my created JSON database using fetch post (localhost:3001).
I wanted to check if my database is being updated when the form is submitted, but apparently I am unable to find the database file anymore even though the form functions well online.
Where could I find my created JSON file after `npm run build` in build folder and hosting provider online?

Answer (score 0):

What engine do you use to support your JSON database to and how are you deploying the React client and the database?

The location of the JSON file would depend on the backend technology you’re using to create and store it. I’d check the browser Console and Network tabs for CORS or other errors.

You shouldn’t be using `localhost:3001` in your deployed app, since localhost is specific to the machine that is running the client (i.e. every visitor of your website would have to have their own server running at `localhost:3001` on their machine). You would need a public URL to your server for this to work (you can use `ngrok` for development, for example).